# compare the magnitude of vector A to vector B

Tags: vectors

compare the magnitude of vector A to vector B if A+B is perpendicular to A-B

now i don't know how to compare this mathematically so i just drew them and i've observed that for them to be perpendicular to each other, the magnitude of A must be equal to B.

if i'm correct, how do you explain this? if not, then what would you say about the magnitudes of A and B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you've never heard of $l_2$-norms ...

The vectors $A+B$ and $A-B$ are the diagonals of a parallelogram. By symmetry, these two diagonals will be perpendicular only if $A$ and $B$ have the same length.

Comment: OH so that means that i'm correct in saying that the magnitude of a must be equal to the magnitude of b for (a+b) and (a-b) to be perpendicular

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: Thanks for the answer, highly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. But why?!

**Hint:** Since $\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b}$, we know that
\begin{align}
(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})^{T}(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b}) = 0.
\end{align}
Try to expand the inner product! 
(Also, note that $\mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{a}=\|\mathbf{a}\|_{2}^{2}$, *i.e.*, the inner product of a vector with itself is equal to its $l_{2}$-norm -- its euclidean length --  squared).

Comment: a^T a - b^T b = 0? then a^T a = b^T b but i still don't get it :(

Comment: does this simply mean that a = b?

Comment: As I write in the hint, $\mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{a}=\|\mathbf{a}\|_{2}^{2}$. Similarly for $\mathbf{b}$. Hence, you get $\|\mathbf{a}\| = \|\mathbf{b}\|$, which is what you want.

Comment: No, it does not mean that $a=b$. That is not true.

Comment: OHHHH THANK YOU SO MUCH